# VB.NET Datagrid

Tags: .net, vb.net

How should I adda datagrid column dynamically on selectedindexedchanged?

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do?
Have a Look at the Columns-Collection (DataGridView.Columns()), it's add Method and the Contrusctor of the DataGridViewtextBoxColumn class.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the Combobox contains datagrid-columns (or Datatable columns) ?

You can simply set the Visible property to false, when you have found the column.

In WinForms:

```
 Dim x as Integer = ...
 dataGridView1.Columns[x].Visible = False
```

But please take a look at your question, it contains virtually no useful information.

Answer (score 0):

In side the selection change event paste this coding

Datagridview1.columncount += 1